# No value given for one or more required parameters while convert excel data to datatable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I know it is a repeated question But I culdn't find as solution for this Thats why I am asking this question again Kindly help me.When I run this code I get error messsage like "No value given for one or more required parameters.". How can I solve it?? My code is

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
   {
       string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
       string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
       string FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];

       string FilePath = Server.MapPath(FolderPath + FileName);
       FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);
       Import_ExcelData_To_Grid(FilePath, Extension, "YES");
   }

 }
```

MY FUNCTION IS

```
 private void Import_ExcelData_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension, string isHDR)
 {

   string conStr = "";
   switch (Extension)
   {
       case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
           conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                    .ConnectionString;
           break;
       case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
           conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                     .ConnectionString;
           break;
   }
   conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
   OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
   OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
   OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

   //Get the name of First Sheet
   connExcel.Open();
   DataTable dtExcelSchema;
   dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
   string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
   connExcel.Close();

   //Read Data from First Sheet
   connExcel.Open();
   cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT [NMAT ID] From [" + SheetName + "]";
   //,[First Name],[Middle Name],[Last Name],[NMAT_SECTION-1-NMIMS], [NMAT_SECTION-2-NMIMS],NMAT_SECTION-3-NMIMS
   oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
   oda.Fill(dt);
   connExcel.Close();

   //Bind Data to GridView
   GridView2.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
   GridView2.DataSource = dt;
   GridView2.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: On which line do you get this ?

Comment: @Mairaj Ahmad, see the last line "oda.Fill(dt);" Here am getting error